# Bootstrap table doesn't change color of cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table that loads data from a json file, what i'm trying to do is that depending on the value of the data in the table, is to color the each cell. those colors are defined in a css file.

I tested the script on a very simple html file and it works, but trying to use that same script to the bootstrap table, it seems it doesn't affect the cell colors.  I'm not sure if because bootstrap tables have their on css style, it may affect the outcome of my script.

my javascript file  color_celda.js

```
function colorCeldas() {


var table = document.getElementById('tablaIndicador'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

var val;

for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
   val= parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10);

      if (val > 75 && val <= 100) { //verde

         cells[i].addClass('verdeBg ');

        } else if (val >= 50 && val <= 75) { //naranja

            cells[i].addClass('orangeBg ');

        } else if (val >= 0 && val < 50) { //rojo

            cells[i].addClass('rojoBg');

        } else  { // sin datos gris


           alert("nada");
           cells[i].addClass('grisBg ');

        }

    }

}
```

the html code

```
...
     <script src="./scripts/color_celda.js"></script>
 ...
<body onload="colorCeldas()">
...  



 <table class="table"  id="tablaIndicador">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Oferta</th>
                        <th>Demanda</th>
                        <th>Seguridad</th>
                        <th>Comunidad Receptora</th>
                        <th>Mercadotecnia</th>
                        <th>Accesibilidad</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos">
                        <td>{{pueblo.oferta}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.demanda}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.seguridad}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.comunidad}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.mercadotecnia}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.accesibilidad}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

EDIT: checking the html file on a web browser throws this message **TypeError: cells[i].addClass is not a function**

EDIT 2: it works on this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zqk6r/401/

just change the css for this one:

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em 0.1em 0.3em;
}


.verdeBg {
    background: green;
}

.orangeBg {
    background: orange;
}

.rojoBg {
    background: red;
}

.grisBg {
    background: gray;
}
```

and the javascript code for this one

```
var val;

for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {

    val = parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10);

       if (val > 75 && val <= 100) { //verde

         cells[i].addClass('verdeBg ');

        } else if (val >= 50 && val <= 75) { //naranja

            cells[i].addClass('orangeBg ');

        } else if (val >= 0 && val < 50) { //rojo

            cells[i].addClass('rojoBg');

        } else  { // sin datos gris

           cells[i].addClass('grisBg ');

        }

}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the document with your browser's tools to see whether 1) the classes are being applied as intended, and 2) they're not being trumped by other style declarations?

Comment: you should be able to determine whether the bootstrap css is overriding your css by looking a dev tool like firebug.  it should show you all css that targets a cell, and what css is active.  it's also possible that your css targeting needs to be adjusted.  you would know this if you don't see your css for the cell in the dev tool at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addClass` is not a native DOM element method, which is why it fails for you.
The `addClass` method is provided by jQuery or (as in the jsfiddle you linked to) the Mootools framework (and probably also a bunch of other JS frameworks).

Mootools takes care to add this method to the element prototype, which is why it works for you in the jsfiddle.

If you are using jQuery then do `$(cells[i]).addClass(className)`.

If you are not using jQuery:

```
var el = cells[i];
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.add(className);
else
  el.className += ' ' + className;
```

Comment: @lftah ok it works!, but for my original html file the table still without changes, but not for the main html one, it seems the cause it's when it loads the json data on the table, **onload()** only works when pressing F5 and **onchange()** doesn't work at all, what event i should use or what other alternative i have to avoid this situation?

Comment: this is worthy of a new question... best and simplest method is that you call a "updateColors" function after you update the table data.  Another possibility is to use `MutationObserver` to observe when the table is changed.